# Execute jquery/js after angularjs controller request

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here is my code:

```
Inspectr.controller('Devices',function ($scope,$http) {
    $http({
        url: 'http://xxeexxx.com/app/inspectr.php',//data
        method: "POST",
        cache : true,
        data: JSON.stringify({  request:'devices', list: 'all'  }),
        headers: {  'Content-Type': 'application/json'  }
    }).then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.cards = data.data;

        runAllMyJqueryScriptsFromHere();
    })
});
```

I am loading some JSON data to a template I have via $routeProvider. 
I need a way to execute jQuery plugins after the template is rendered and all data is loaded.

The function

```
runAllMyJqueryScriptsFromHere()
```

contains all my jquery's that need to fire after $http is loaded.

Comment: EDIT: For reference https://chris.lu/article/read/506de698268c420f0d000004
One way could be to lazy-load jquery from the $http callback.

Comment: it doesn't work. it fires too soon most of the times. need a proper callback

Comment: You have some other issue going on, as the first argument to then will only execute once the deferred ($http) is resolved.

Comment: yes, when $http is resolved, but not when HTML is rendered using the data recovered. I need loaded template + data to be rendered and then execute JS

Comment: Jquery is best run in directives with Angular, as jquery usually has to do with DOM manipulation. Could you show us why you are not doing this in this usecase?

Comment: well I'm not that familiar I guess with the use of directives. Could you show us how?

Comment: You will have to show us an example of one of the commands you are running in runAllMyJqueryScriptsFromHere(). Here is some documentation on directives: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it's done

```
Inspectr.controller('Devices',function ($scope,$http) {
    $http({
        url: 'http://xxeexxx.com/app/inspectr.php',//data
        method: "POST",
        cache : true,
        data: JSON.stringify({  request:'devices', list: 'all'  }),
        headers: {  'Content-Type': 'application/json'  }
    }).then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
           $scope.cards = data.data;
           runAllMyJqueryScriptsFromHere();
        });


    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a timeout and its gonna work. BTW there is no 'onrender' browser event so its impossible to register your self after browser repaint is done. You have to use an $timeout to timeout function execution.

```
Inspectr.controller('Devices',function ($scope,$http, $timeout) {
    $http({
        url: 'http://xxeexxx.com/app/inspectr.php',//data
        method: "POST",
        cache : true,
        data: JSON.stringify({  request:'devices', list: 'all'  }),
        headers: {  'Content-Type': 'application/json'  }
    }).then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.cards = data.data;
        $timeout(function(){
           runAllMyJqueryScriptsFromHere();
        }, 0); // time here
    })
});
```

What also you can do is you can register onload event:

```
<div ng-view data-onload="onloadfunctionfromscope"></div>
```

Which will be evaluated after template load:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#methods_$eval
But inside you have to use $timeout.